# Dagger listener/interface injection

Tags: android, dependency-injection, code-injection

Hello everyone I've been struggling to understand how to inject a listener to a main activtity with Dagger2, I wonder if what I'm trying to do is possible or even a right move with dagger or should I just let it like it is right now I have read that I need to create another class with the implementation of that interface but is not possible(or recommended) to inject on the mainactivity?, thanks in advance to anyone who can help me, I have everything in short as follows:

//////////////////////////////////////MainActivity.class//////////////////////////////////////

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CustomListener{
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            //this is the object I want to inject in Dagger
            LongProcess longProcess = new LongProcess(this);
            longProcess.longRunningProcess();
    }
   @Override
    public void onProcessStarted() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onProcessStarted: CALLBACK!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onProcessFailed() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onProcessFailed: CALLBACK!");
    }}
```

//////////////////////////////////////LongProcess.class//////////////////////////////////////

```
public class LongProcess {
 private CustomListener customListener;
 public LongProcess(CustomListener customListener) {
    this.customListener = customListener;
}


public void longRunningProcess() {
    try {
        //some long process started...
        customListener.onProcessStarted();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        //some long process failed...
        customListener.onProcessFailed();
    }
}
}
```

//////////////////////////////////////interface.java//////////////////////////////////////

```
public interface CustomListener {

    void onProcessStarted();
    void onProcessFailed();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at Assisted Injection for this use case: https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/assisted-injection